# How can I use a link to open file automatically instead of showing open save dialog?

Tags: html, hyperlink, powerpoint

I am trying to open a PPT file. I don't want to show the *Save As* dialog. I instead just want to open the file immediately on click. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You need to take two things into account:

1. The HTTP [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2183) header -if any- should be set to `inline`, not `attachment`. The later will indeed force the client to display a *Save As* dialogue.
2. The HTTP [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header should contain a mime type which is recognized by the client as being a PPT file which is usually [`application/vnd.ms-powerpoint`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types). When using `inline` and the browser really don't know what to do with it (i.e. there is no application associated with the content type or extension according to the underlying platform/OS), then it will open the *Save As* regardless.

You can debug the response headers using tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). You can modify response headers in server side code and/or webserver configuration. If you tell which language and/or webserver you're using, then we may be able to give more specific solutions.

Comment: He is opening it through a link

Comment: @Sarfraz: that's correct. Do you understand the problem/question anyway?

Comment: +1 for setting Content-Disposition to inline - I had to do something similar recently myself - @silverlightCache, do you have access to your server?  Can you ssh in to it?  If so, you might be able to stick a perl script into the cgi-bin (if you have one) that sets the Content-Header.  If you're using a scripting language for your development, then look at the reference materials to see if there's a pre-baked method to let you set the headers.  Failing that, you can always modify your Apache Config (or Nginx config) to set the Headers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser setting. You can try to force a save dialog with `Content-disposition`, but not vice-versa. I don't think there's much you can except tell your users to choose to "Always open files of this type".

Comment: Correct, but you can cheat, forcing a specific MIME-type (like application).

Comment: @Konerak: Sending the wrong MIME type would be nasty. I hope people don't start doing that.

Comment: This (Firefox-typical) browser setting only applies to `Content-Disposition: attachment`. When using `inline` and the browser really don't know what to do with it (i.e. no application associated with contenttype/extension according to the underlying platform/OS), then it will open the *Save As* regardless.

Comment: I'm quite sure there is no way to force a browser to launch an external application automatically from the server side, even if an application has already been associated with the file type. Plugins are another thing, but I don't remember MSOffice coming with browser plugins.